# How can I visualize and cluster weighted graphs in python?

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, unsupervised-learning, graph-theory, networks

On any ecommerce website, you have options to apply filters to filter out products. For example:

[image]

So I have data of how many users applied what filters tuples on the website. Which is fetched from google analytics in this format:

```
Table 1

BRANDS              | USERS
---------------------------
HP, Dell, Apple     | 3
Dell, HP            | 5
Microsoft, Apple    | 5
Microsoft, Micromax | 1
HP, Dell, Acer      | 3
Dell, Apple         | 7
HP, Microsoft       | 3
```

This means for ex. that there were 3 unique users who applied HP,Dell,Apple triplet as a filter on the website

So this data represents that there is some corelation score between every pair of brand. I want to cluster the brands using this count. And also want to visualize the clusters with a plot.

So far, I converted the inputs to a weighed networkx object where nodes are the unique brands and weights of the edges are the sum of all the `USERS` where that vertices pair exist.

So the data becomes:
`Nodes : Acer, Apple, Dell, HP, Micromax, Microsoft`

Weighted Edges:

```
Table 2

Acer, Dell, 3
Acer, HP, 3
Apple, Dell, 10
Apple, HP, 3
Apple, Microsoft, 5
Dell, HP, 11
HP, Microsoft, 3
Micromax, Microsoft, 1
```

I'm planning to plot the graph with a Kamada Kawai layout. Another name thats popping up in my searches is Fruchterman Reingold visualization. However I believe that there must be some even better ways that I have not thought of or found out in my research.

I'm using python. My total `no. of brands` are of order of `200` and `edges weights` are in range `approx 1-150`
My total data points are around 3000 in the `Table1` format.

Please guide me to cluster my data and visualize it.
Would appretiate references to code snippets or blogs for similar problems.
Thanks for the help!